# The type TransactionCallback is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments [Ao entity]

Tags: java, generics, active-objects

In below stuff, shows me an error as "The type TransactionCallback is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments " in eclipse editor.

```
import com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionCallback;

ao.executeInTransaction(new TransactionCallback<EntityIssues>() // (1)

{

@Override

public Todo doInTransaction()

{

//storing stuff

}

});

<dependency>

<groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>

<artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>

<version>2.0.17</version>

<scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>
```

my JAVASE version is - 1.7.0

any idea why it does not taking generic object ?

Comment: Have you then tried to remove the generic parameterization? I.e. `new TransactionCallback()`?

Comment: By removing generic parameterization, it works. Thanks. Not sure why it did not work for generic.

Comment: i am unable to mark your comment as answer...

Comment: I've added an answer, great that it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply remove the generic parameterization:

```java
new TransactionCallback()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the TransactionCallback is not generic in version [2.0.17](http://repository.atlassian.com/maven2/com/atlassian/sal/sal-api/2.0.17/). The generic parameter is introduced in later versions.

Comment: I have updated to "<version>2.7.1</version>" and compiled and refreshed eclipse project. Though, it shows same error in eclipse intelligence. I have also tried by directly give external jar reference for 2.7.0/1 both. though, same.... no effect..